# Check if attribute contains 2 letters in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

What is the right way to test if the field contains 2 letter string with RSpec ? I am following an old example that I guess worked in rails 2. It creates new `Address` instance, sets invalid value on it, and then trigger `valid?` on that instance and finally checks if the `errors` report something wrong.

```
  it 'requires state to be of length 2' do
      subject = Address.new
      subject.state = 'Cal'
      should_not be_valid
      subject.errors.on(:state).should_not be_nil
    end
```

Now, Rails 3 doesn't have errors.on, so I tried with

```
subject.errors[:state].should_not be_nil
```

But the problem here is that `errors[:attribute]` is empty `Array` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still say

```
subject.errors[:state].should_not be_empty
```

Comment: That works, thanks.Just one question, in your opinion is there a more preferred to test this ?

Comment: you could use shoulda validation helpers.     `it {should_not allow_value("Cal").for(:state)}`

Answer (score 0):

Validation errors are now in `errors.messages`

```
errors.messages.should be_present
```